# caffeine cache refreshAfterWrite method throwing refreshAfterWrite requires a LoadingCache exception

Tags: spring, caching, caffeine

I have a requirement on re cache the expired cache by calling the API again

The below is my cache manager configuration

```
private CaffeineCache buildCache(
    String name,
    Ticker ticker,
    int minutesToExpire
) {
    return new CaffeineCache(name, Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .refreshAfterWrite(minutesToExpire, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(100)
                .ticker(ticker)
                .build());
}
```

But while starting the application it is throwing the below exception

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: refreshAfterWrite requires a LoadingCache

Comment: Caffeine requires the builder is given a loading function to refresh with.

Comment: Could you please suggest how to create that

Comment: You would use the [build(key -> ...)](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Population#loading) method. This provides a `CacheLoader` that is invoked to reload with.

Comment: Documentation says .build(key -> createExpensiveGraph(key)); ..But which class contains this createExpensiveGraph() method

Comment: That's an example, it is whatever function computes the value. Ideally this would be the method you annotate with `@Cacheable`, but Spring Cache isn't able to give that upfront like Caffeine requires for this feature.

Comment: ok got it.Thank you.So is there any better way to do it

Comment: In this case you should use Caffeine’s cache api directly instead of the annotations, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you..Do you have any working example for this

Comment: You could inject the built `LoadingCache`. If you want to build it in the class but externalize the configuration, you might inject `CaffeineSpec` instead. Unfortunately I don't have Spring examples since I don't use it myself.

Comment: ok thanks..not able to find a working example in internet thought

Comment: You would use the native apis and not Spring Cache, e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/java-caching-caffeine

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a [CacheLoader](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.github.ben-manes.caffeine/caffeine/2.8.5/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/cache/CacheLoader.html) to the `build` method.

```
return new CaffeineCache(
        name,
        Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .refreshAfterWrite(minutesToExpire, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(100)
                .ticker(ticker)
                .build(key -> createExpensiveObject(key))
);
```

The CacheLoader is a class/method that has to be implemented by you.